# Too many open files when using Memcached for sessions

Tags: symfony, nginx, memcached, php

I'm using ubuntu + nginx + php5-fpm + symfony2, and I recently switched from files to Memcached (php5-memcached) for sessions. 
Since then, I've started to get 500 response code errors after a while. This is what it looks like in the error logs (**failed to open stream: Too many open**):

```
"PHP message: PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(.../vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.xml): failed to open stream: Too many open files in .../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/XmlDriver.php on line 736
PHP message: PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;.../vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.xml&quot; in .../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/XmlDriver.php on line 736
PHP message: PHP Warning:  include(.../vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php): failed to open stream: Too many open files in .../vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 382
```

After some research, I've found out that it seems to be related to the usage of Memcached for sessions:

1. Those are the php5-fpm processes running:

   ps aux | grep php

   root      3233  0.0  0.2 207464 16164 ?        Ss   Mar16   0:02 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
   www-data  3236  0.0  0.8 238796 65796 ?        S    Mar16   0:50 php-fpm:     pool www
   www-data  3646  0.0  0.7 231176 57808 ?        S    Mar16   0:42 php-fpm: pool www
   www-data  7503  0.1  0.7 234820 59920 ?        S    11:52   0:34 php-fpm: pool www
   ubuntu    8224  0.0  0.0  10436   860 pts/0    S+   16:53   0:00 grep --color=auto php

2.Checking any of the php5-fpm childs with lsof, it shows, among other things that there were 1k+ open file descriptors pointing to the Memcache instance with an established connection:

```
sudo lsof -p 3236

…
php5-fpm 3236 www-data  672u  IPv4             107781      0t0    TCP hostname:54403->memcacheIp:11211 (ESTABLISHED)
php5-fpm 3236 www-data  673u  IPv4             108827      0t0    TCP hostname:54411->memcacheIp:11211 (ESTABLISHED)
php5-fpm 3236 www-data  674u  IPv4             107800      0t0    TCP hostname:54418->memcacheIp:11211 (ESTABLISHED)
...
```

Over one thousand entries like that, which I think starts failing when it arrives to 1024, which is the limit of open file descriptors:

```
ulimit  -n
1024
```

The thing is that this is a QA environment which is not used for more than 1 or 2 concurrent users, so there is no way all those open file descriptors are active sessions. I noticed that every time I make a request to the symfony2 application, a new socket connection to the memcache server is opened, but then it's never closed. So, eventually it reaches the limit at starts failing. I thought might be something related with timeout connections or something like that but haven't found anything so far.

Restarting php5-fpm seems to "solve" the problem, but only until another 1k requests are made.

I've temporarily switched back to files and the problem disappears. Also I've tried using `Memcache` (`php5-memcache`) instead of `Memcached` and the problem is solved but I'd rather use `php5-memcached` as it seems better maintained.

Any ideas of how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much!

If it helps, the specific php version that I'm using:

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6 (cli) (built: Feb 13 2015 19:17:11) 
libmemcached version => 1.0.8
```

Comment: try tuning the value simply increase it and see what happen. Otherwise try only se to unimited value (`ulimit -n unlimited`). Hope this help

Comment: Thanks but that wouldn't solve the problem, it would just delay it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution thanks to this:

http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.construct.php (see @Tobias comment)

and this https://gist.github.com/K-Phoen/4327229 (see @cmenning comment)

I was using Memcached with a sessions.yml as follows:

```
session.memcached:
    class: Memcached
    arguments:
       persistent_id: %session_memcached_prefix%
    calls:
        - [ addServer, [ %session_memcached_host%, %session_memcached_port% ]]

session.handler.memcached:
    class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcachedSessionHandler
    arguments: [@session.memcached, { prefix: %session_memcached_prefix%, expiretime: %session_memcached_expire% }]
```

It turns out that if you provide a persistent_id argument for Memcached it would persist the connection between requests. From php.net:

persistent_id

> By default the Memcached instances are destroyed at the end of the
>   request. To create an instance that persists between requests, use
>   persistent_id to specify a unique ID for the instance. All instances
>   created with the same persistent_id will share the same connection.

The problem is that if you use a persistent_id (Which is better for performance), you have to check if there are already servers added before calling `addServer`, otherwise it would add a new server & create a new connection, even though it's the same server (it doesn't check for dupes. 
Something like this:

```
        $instance = new Memcached($persistent_id);

        // Add server if no connections listed. 
        if (!count($instance->getServerList())) {
            $instance->addServers($server);
        }
```

But for that you'd need to create a wrapper class of Memcached. The easy fix is just to comment out this lines, and avoid using persistent connections for the moment:

```
    #arguments:
    #  persistent_id: %session_memcached_prefix%
```

This solves the issue, even though it's not ideal.
I hope it helps you to save some time and avoid a headache!
Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem which we fixed by caching metadata in memcache in your config.yml

```
 orm:

    default_entity_manager:   default
    entity_managers:
      default:
         metadata_cache_driver:
             type: memcache
             host: localhost
             port: 11211
             instance_class: Memcache
         query_cache_driver:
             type: memcache
             host: localhost
             port: 11211
             instance_class: Memcache
```

Otherwise if you prefere to cache via apc it also fixes it, i tried both :

```
 metadata_cache_driver: apc
 query_cache_driver: apc
```

Hope this helped, for more informations about this issue : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1062#issuecomment-29473883

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's the same issue, as in my case it's failing to open the file because the system has reached the limit of maximum open file descriptors, whereas that error seems to be an issue parsing the file.

Comment: ah my bad i didn't notice the "failed to open stream: Too many open files in" as i was obsessed with that error lately.. i assume restarting the memcache and clearing the cache would temporary fix it?

Comment: Restarting php5-fpm temporary fixes it (probably restarting memcache would as well), but you know, just *temporary*! hehe. I need a proper solution... thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: btw if you use the metadata caching in memcache or apc it doesnt keep loading xml data from files it does it once so i still think it may fix it

Comment: I gave it a try just in case, but the issue remains. The only difference is that now fails trying to open a different file: `PHP message: PHP Warning:  include(.../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/Exception/FatalErrorException.php): failed to open stream: Too many open files in .../vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 382` but it's the same error.